# Unexpected behaviour replacing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

sorry for the long post, i tried to make it as readable as possible.

I have a decent knowledge of JAVA and trying to understand Android programming. Today i have been working on my knowledge of fragments.

I have read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and got the basics of working with them.I managed to make fragments and replace them when needed.

I proceeded by taking [this project](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/), and thought it might be fun to try and add a fragment to it with a basic tictactoe game i had build for practising purposes.

Now i am having problems with replacing the fragment. Everything works fine until I add the TicTacToe view in the mix, which has a tablelayout. The fragment is not getting replaced, rather is it adding an extra fragment (or so it seems) and uses this to switch fragments in.

`BoardField` is simply a class I made which `extends Button`

The layout thats not working for me is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0f0fdf">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.BoardField android:id="@+id/my_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonDefault"
        android:onClick="selected"
        />
    <com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.BoardField android:id="@+id/my_button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonDefault"/>
    <com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.BoardField android:id="@+id/my_button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonDefault"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I omitted the other rows for readability, they are similar.

So my question is, why is replacing the fragments not working when I use TableLayout ??

EDIT:

Eric's solution worked, i hope to find out more about why?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking for ... *why is replacing the fragments not working* what do you mean by this (any code) ... what is a BoardField class ? ... *The fragment is not getting replaced* < ???

Comment: @Selvin, i tried to make it clear as possible. I will use your feedback to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Selvin Also i don't understand your downvote, other people seem to understand just fine and provide an actual solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why parent view is TableLayout? Try to changing it to a RelativeLayout with a child, the TableLayout (just for test purpose)

With a RelativeLayout as parent view, are you able to "replace" instead of "add" the Fragment?

Comment: Wow! , it instantly solved my problem. 
Why can't TableLayout be parent? (is this a stupid question?). I had done it like that because i figured a 3x3 grid would fit nice in a tablelayout

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is not here. Perhaps your can look in code where you create new fragment or code where you replace fragment. There is no sense TableLayout make a problem to replace fragment. Eric is right RelativeLayout is better then TableLayout, but this is not the problem. Can you put more of your code?

Comment: it should be a comment ... but i agree with you - problem is not a TableLayout

Comment: @Sniper Read the edit at the bottom of my question, Eric's solution (putting tableLayout inside RelativeLayout) helped! I would like to know why it helped though...

Comment: Also when tableLayout is used, i am seeing it twice on my screen after "replacing"

Comment: debug your fragment code, and the code where you replace the fragment and check does your fragment code is not executed twice, or does you haven't two fragment instances.

Comment: I am sure that its being created one, but might it have

Comment: The only reason I can think of, is that i'm setting the fragment in main_activity.xml

android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentThree"

and I am creating it in my Java file once